# Отображение checkboxes в разных браузерах

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, checkbox

Здравствуйте,

Столкнулся с проблемой. Чекбоксы на Хроме и Опере отображаются совершенно по разному. И если на Хроме отображение корректное:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 то на Опере вообще ужас:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HTML:

```html
<p style="font-size: 17pt; font-weight: 600;">What kinds of web support services do you need?*</p>
<p><input name="services[]" type="checkbox" value="Updating the content of the website (articles, photos, videos, prices etc.)" /> <br />Updating the content of the website (articles, photos, videos, prices etc.)</p>
<p><input name="services[]" type="checkbox" value="Backing up Files (once a week)" /> <br />Backing up Files (once a week)</p>
<p><input name="services[]" type="checkbox" value="Updating Website Software" /><br />Updating Website Software</p>
<p><input name="services[]" type="checkbox" value="Fixing HTML/CSS/PHP/JavaScript errors and bugs" /> <br />Fixing HTML/CSS/PHP/JavaScript errors and bugs</p>
<p><input name="services[]" type="checkbox" value="Sitemap generation" /> <br />Sitemap generation</p>
<p><input name="services[]" type="checkbox" value="Website performance and uptime monitoring" /> <br />Website performance and uptime monitoring</p>
<p><input name="services[]" type="checkbox" value="Suggestions for website improvements" /> <br />Suggestions for website improvements</p>
<p><input name="services[]" type="checkbox" value="Regular reporting and feedback" /> <br />Regular reporting and feedback</p>
<p><input name="services[]" type="checkbox" value="I'm not sure. Help me please" /><br /><i>I'm not sure. Help me please</i></p>
<p><input name="services[]" type="checkbox" value="I need a full package of services" /><br /><b>I need a full package of services</b></p>
```

СSS:

```css
.contactform div form p input {
    width: 71%;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 20pt;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 2px solid #eabd20;
```

Как можно в этом случае сделать чтобы опера отображала чекбоксы тоже по центру, а не где-то сбоку?

Answer (score 5):

Используйте кроссбраузерные псевдочекбоксы:

```css
input {
  display: none;
}

span::after {
  content: '☐';
}

input:checked+span::after {
  content: '☑';
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <span></span>  
</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

Согласно стандарту HTML, браузер **не обязан** уважать подавляюще большинство стилей CSS на инпутах. Количество стилей, которые браузер обязан применять к инпутам, очень ограничено, и всякие границы и фоны в их число не входят.

Не знаю, зачем вам сдалась ископаемая версия упокоившейся с миром Оперы, но какой-нибудь Сафари будет игнорировать ещё больше стилей инпутов.

Если вам нужно стилизовать инпуты, то рисуйте их сами с помощью полноценных элементов HTML, а затем привязывайте их к реальным инпутам. В случае с checkbox это можно сделать как показано в ответе **@br3t**.